# PowerShell Ping script for gathering host names

Tags: powershell

I am a Network Engineer and my scripting skills are basically none. I work in an Enterprise data center (for only 6 months) and we have an IP spreadsheet. And in having this Spreadsheet comes errors. and if not corrected they  snowball and become bigger than they needed to be.

I have been tasked with finding out the host name given to a certain IP within our whole enterprise. Doing this by hand one by one would take months to do. Is there a way to write a script to do it for me? I am looking at 1000s of IPs if not 10000's of IPs. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

What I need is a script that will either ping or look in DNS to find the host name to any given IP address. and then put the output to a file so the IP spreadsheet can be updated.

I am at a loss for this, Like I said any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Put your code and attempts. SO is not a free code writing service, find another site or try yourself and we can help you with that.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Ideally when you are asking a question it's good to share what you have done, some examples and expected output.  Here is an example that might help you to start - https://askme4tech.com/how-resolve-ip-address-hostname-powershell and possibly provide more details so someone can help.

Comment: In addition to my previous speakers I have to say, that it is even disrespectful to expect others to spend their free time to do the work for you, you get paid for. Seriously, (re-)read the help topic [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take it to heart.

Comment: First of all I never asked for anyone to write the script for me. All I asked is can a script do it and I laid out what I wanted it to do. Frankly it is disrespectful to assume I was asking for anyone to do it for me. I said my scripting skills were none, but that does not mean I learn to do it. Maybe I should have asked for a good starting point for what I wanted. So you can step down off your Ivory tower looking down on me. I have exhausted all the resources I could to try to find a way to do this.  Thank for for re-enforcing my thoughts on sites and people like this.

Comment: @RDrew - you are taking this as a direct attack, it seems. the point is that you did not read the intro ... and are asking a question that directly violates the stated intent of this site. i have read, re-read, and re-re-read the comments here and they have all be fairly polite. please, do not presume that criticism is an attack.

Comment: I am not presuming anything. In fact when the majority of the comments assume I asked someone to write the script for me or as one guy said do the work for me, for what I get paid for. So you answer your question. so far the only to actually help me out is @Anhish Kumar directing me to a site where I can start to compile and start the script. If you have read these comments then I ask you to read them again and see what I am seeing. Again, I never asked anyone to write the code for me. Maybe the original post was lacking in asking for a good starting point. Thank you for your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a go:

```
Get-Content C:\temp\IP_Addresses.txt | ForEach-Object {([system.net.dns]::GetHostByAddress($_)).hostname >> c:\temp\hostname.txt}
```

Found it on Technet, you will need to extract your ip's into a text list and it does not de-duplicate, but should be a nice starting point.

Comment: Thank you for that I have started to create and work out any kinks I find. Once again Thank you for your help.

Comment: Pleasure. When you have a 'working' script, post it for review if you need help with the kinks.